# How to Loop and pick every string in a file and search the same from a folder

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have a folder called error which contains some 1000 files like below:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 orartkp6 dba         1298 Apr 19 09:23 BEN_INV_5_0900091010993_20160419092353.xml.err
-rw-r--r--   1 orartkp6 dba         1289 Apr 19 09:23 BEN_INV_5_0900091010994_20160419092353.xml.err
-rw-r--r--   1 orartkp6 dba         1286 Apr 19 09:23 BEN_INV_5_0900091010995_20160419092353.xml.err
-rw-r--r--   1 orartkp6 dba         1292 Apr 19 09:23 BEN_INV_5_0900091010996_20160419092353.xml.err
-rw-r--r--   1 orartkp6 dba         1300 Apr 19 09:23 BEN_INV_5_0900091010997_20160419092353.xml.err
```

Now I have a `.txt` file which has say only 500 of the above file **names**.
SO now I have to write a script to read every line from the `.txt` file and search inside the error folder and move only those 500 files into a new folder (backup_folder).

Can you help me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

the logic behind this would be,
read only $2 column that is (i suppose) the names of the files,
and in a while loop output each one in a variable and then use mv.

```
awk '{print $2; var=$2; mv $var dir_to_move}' 500lines.txt
```

hope i helped.

Answer (score 0):

I used the below while loop to solve this problem.

while read file
do
cp -p "$file" ./backup_folder
done < 500lines.txt